# Is it possible to post videos on LinkedIn that play automatically?

Tags: video, linkedin

We posted a video on linked in but it does not automatically play when scrolling the feed.

I [read](https://martech.org/linkedin-starts-letting-people-natively-upload-videos-play-automatically/) that in 2017 linked.in started allowing users to post videos as autoplay.

Is this still possible and how? We did not find such an option.
Or is it only possible for video ads?

Answer (score 1):

Try a video without sound. Videos with sound often not allowed to autoplay.

Comment: It does not have audio, but might have a audio-track (at least I can regulate the volume in the player). Not sure if the audio-track needs to be fully deleted.